# Making a new variable with java

Tags: java, variables

Trying to figure out how to create new varaibles. If your input is 2 (2 teens) and they both order, the total amount will only be the last teen's order as the the variable for each teens order will be stored in the same variable. I am trying to figure out how to create new variables if there is more than one of the same type of person eating at this restaurant.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Lab9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables
        int totalGuest;
        int selectOne;
        int selectTwo;
        int selectThree;
        int i;

        //Wing Variables
        double wingAmount;

        //Meal Variables 
        double optionTotalOne = 0;
        double optionTotalTwo = 0;
        double optionTotalThree = 0;

        //Totals
        double discountOneTotal = 0;
        double discountTwoTotal = 0;
        double discountThreeTotal = 0;
        double discountFourTotal = 0;

        double entireAmount = 0;



        //Menu Array
        String menu[] = new String[9];
        menu[0] = "Soup";
        menu[1] = "Wings";
        menu[2] = "Burger";
        menu[3] = "Chicken Sandwhich";
        menu[4] = "Fries";
        menu[5] = "Pie";
        menu[6] = "Ice cream";
        menu[7] = "Soft drink"; 
        menu[8] = "Coffee";

        //Price Array
        double prices[] = new double[9];
        prices[0] = 2.50;
        prices[1] = .15;
        prices[2] = 4.95;
        prices[3] = 5.95;
        prices[4] = 1.99;
        prices[5] = 2.95;
        prices[6] = 2.99;
        prices[7] = 1.50;
        prices[8] = 1.00;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please type a value for NUMBER_IN_PARTY: ");
            totalGuest = input.nextInt();

            //for-loop
            for (i = 1; i <= totalGuest; i++) {

                //Order input for i-th customer
                System.out.println("\n \nPlease input order information for person " + i + "\n \n");

                //Discount menu displayed
                System.out.println("Is this person eligible for a discount? (enter a number 1 - 4)" +
                        "\n1 - if CHILD 5 years of age or younger \n2 - if TEEN between 13 and 19 years of age"
                        + "\n3 - if SENIOR 65 years of age or older \n4 - if NONE of the above \nPlease type a value for DISCOUNT_TYPE: ");
                int discount = input.nextInt();

                //If else statement
                if (discount == 1) {

                    //Price Array for children 5 & under
                    prices[0] = 0;
                    prices[1] = 0;
                    prices[2] = 0;
                    prices[3] = 0;
                    prices[4] = 0;
                    prices[5] = 0;
                    prices[6] = 0;
                    prices[7] = 0;
                    prices[8] = 0;

                    //Menu output
                    System.out.println("Menu items that may be selected: \n1 " + menu[0] + "\n2 " + 
                            menu[1] + "\n3 " + menu[2] + "\n4 " + menu[3] + "\n5 " + menu[4] + "\n6 " + menu[5] +
                            "\n7 " + menu[6] + "\n8 " + menu[7] + "\n9 " + menu[8]);

                    //Menu Item 1 prompt
                    System.out.println("\n \nPlease select menu item 1 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectOne = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectOne) {
                    case 1: optionTotalOne = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalOne = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalOne = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalOne = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalOne = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalOne = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalOne = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalOne = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalOne = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 2 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 2 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectTwo = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectTwo) {
                    case 1: optionTotalTwo = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalTwo = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalTwo = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalTwo = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalTwo = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalTwo = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalTwo = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalTwo = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalTwo = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 3 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 3 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectThree = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectThree) {
                    case 1: optionTotalThree = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalThree = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalThree = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalThree = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalThree = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalThree = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalThree = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalThree = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalThree = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Discount One Total
                    discountOneTotal = optionTotalOne + optionTotalTwo + optionTotalThree;
                    System.out.printf("Person " + i + " Total: $%.2f" + " (Discount Type 1)", discountOneTotal);

                } else if (discount == 2) {

                    //Price Array Teens & Seniors
                    prices[0] = 2.625 * .75;
                    prices[1] = .1575 * .75;
                    prices[2] = 5.1975 * .75;
                    prices[3] = 6.2475 * .75;
                    prices[4] = 2.0895 * .75;
                    prices[5] = 3.0975 * .75;
                    prices[6] = 3.1395 * .75;
                    prices[7] = 1.575 *.75;
                    prices[8] = 1.05 * .75;

                    //Menu output
                    System.out.println("Menu items that may be selected: \n1 " + menu[0] + "\n2 " + 
                            menu[1] + "\n3 " + menu[2] + "\n4 " + menu[3] + "\n5 " + menu[4] + "\n6 " + menu[5] +
                            "\n7 " + menu[6] + "\n8 " + menu[7] + "\n9 " + menu[8]);

                    //Menu Item 1 prompt
                    System.out.println("\n \nPlease select menu item 1 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectOne = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectOne) {
                    case 1: optionTotalOne = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalOne = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalOne = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalOne = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalOne = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalOne = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalOne = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalOne = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalOne = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 2 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 2 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectTwo = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectTwo) {
                    case 1: optionTotalTwo = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalTwo = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalTwo = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalTwo = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalTwo = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalTwo = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalTwo = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalTwo = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalTwo = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 3 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 3 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectThree = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectThree) {
                    case 1: optionTotalThree = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalThree = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalThree = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalThree = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalThree = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalThree = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalThree = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalThree = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalThree = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Discount One Total
                    discountTwoTotal = optionTotalOne + optionTotalTwo + optionTotalThree;
                    System.out.printf("Person " + i + " Total: $%.2f" + " (Discount Type 2)", discountTwoTotal);


                }
                else if (discount == 3) {

                    //Price Array Teens & Seniors
                    prices[0] = 2.625 * .75;
                    prices[1] = .1575 * .75;
                    prices[2] = 5.1975 * .75;
                    prices[3] = 6.2475 * .75;
                    prices[4] = 2.0895 * .75;
                    prices[5] = 3.0975 * .75;
                    prices[6] = 3.1395 * .75;
                    prices[7] = 1.575 *.75;
                    prices[8] = 1.05 * .75;

                    //Menu output
                    System.out.println("Menu items that may be selected: \n1 " + menu[0] + "\n2 " + 
                            menu[1] + "\n3 " + menu[2] + "\n4 " + menu[3] + "\n5 " + menu[4] + "\n6 " + menu[5] +
                            "\n7 " + menu[6] + "\n8 " + menu[7] + "\n9 " + menu[8]);

                    //Menu Item 1 prompt
                    System.out.println("\n \nPlease select menu item 1 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectOne = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectOne) {
                    case 1: optionTotalOne = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalOne = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalOne = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalOne = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalOne = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalOne = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalOne = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalOne = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalOne = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 2 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 2 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectTwo = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectTwo) {
                    case 1: optionTotalTwo = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalTwo = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalTwo = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalTwo = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalTwo = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalTwo = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalTwo = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalTwo = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalTwo = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 3 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 3 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectThree = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectThree) {
                    case 1: optionTotalThree = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalThree = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalThree = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalThree = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalThree = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalThree = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalThree = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalThree = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalThree = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    discountFourTotal = optionTotalOne + optionTotalTwo + optionTotalThree;
                    System.out.printf("Person " + i + " Total: $%.2f" + " (Discount Type 3)", discountFourTotal);
                }else if (discount == 4) {

                    //Price Array for Adults
                    prices[0] += (.05 * prices[0]);
                    prices[1] += (.05 * prices[1]);
                    prices[2] += (.05 * prices[2]);
                    prices[3] += (.05 * prices[3]);
                    prices[4] += (.05 * prices[4]);
                    prices[5] += (.05 * prices[5]);
                    prices[6] += (.05 * prices[6]);
                    prices[7] += (.05 * prices[7]);
                    prices[8] += (.05 * prices[8]);

                    //Menu output
                    System.out.println("Menu items that may be selected: \n1 " + menu[0] + "\n2 " + 
                            menu[1] + "\n3 " + menu[2] + "\n4 " + menu[3] + "\n5 " + menu[4] + "\n6 " + menu[5] +
                            "\n7 " + menu[6] + "\n8 " + menu[7] + "\n9 " + menu[8]);

                    //Menu Item 1 prompt
                    System.out.println("\n \nPlease select menu item 1 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectOne = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectOne) {
                    case 1: optionTotalOne = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalOne = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalOne = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalOne = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalOne = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalOne = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalOne = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalOne = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalOne = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }


                    //Menu Item 2 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 2 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectTwo = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectTwo) {
                    case 1: optionTotalTwo = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalTwo = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalTwo = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalTwo = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalTwo = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalTwo = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalTwo = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalTwo = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalTwo = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    }

                    //Menu Item 3 prompt
                    System.out.println("Please select menu item 3 (enter a number 1 - 9) \nPlease type a value for SELECTED_ITEM: ");
                    selectThree = input.nextInt();

                    //Switch Statement
                    switch(selectThree) {
                    case 1: optionTotalThree = prices[0];
                    break;
                    case 2: System.out.println("Please enter number of wings to be ordered \nPlease type a value for NUMBER_OF_WINGS: ");
                    wingAmount = input.nextInt();
                    optionTotalThree = wingAmount * prices[1];
                    break;
                    case 3: optionTotalThree = prices[2];
                    break;
                    case 4: optionTotalThree = prices[3];
                    break;
                    case 5: optionTotalThree = prices[4];
                    break;
                    case 6: optionTotalThree = prices[5];
                    break;
                    case 7: optionTotalThree = prices[6];
                    break;
                    case 8: optionTotalThree = prices[7];
                    break;
                    case 9: optionTotalThree = prices[8];
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("This is not an option on the menu.");
                    break;
                    }

                    //Discount One Total
                    discountThreeTotal = optionTotalOne + optionTotalTwo + optionTotalThree;
                    System.out.printf("Person " + i + " Total: $%.2f" + " (Discount Type 4)", discountThreeTotal);
                }
            }
            }while(i <= totalGuest);

        //Total Amount Printed
        entireAmount = discountOneTotal + discountTwoTotal + discountFourTotal + discountThreeTotal;
        System.out.println(discountOneTotal + "  " + discountTwoTotal + "  " + discountThreeTotal + "  " + discountFourTotal);
        System.out.printf("\n\nGrand Total for Order: $%.2f", entireAmount);

        //Closed Scanner Object
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't create variables at runtime. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: The answer you're probably looking for is "use an array or a `List`". That being said, your code is in very dire need of some serious refactoring. No point of doing OO programming if you're not gonna use any objects. Might as well write the whole thing in C (and even then you'd need some serious refactoring).

Comment: I think you want array whose size is equal to the input. Then you want to loop, each time creating a new 'teen', adding it to the array.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Even with C, this is begging for structs.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, the simplest option would be to turn your total variables into arrays, for example:

```
double[] discountOneTotal;
double[] discountTwoTotal;
double[] discountThreeTotal;
double[] discountFourTotal;
```

These are currently uninitialized, so you'll have to initialize them after you get the number of guests, for example:

```
discountOneTotal = new double[totalGuest];
discountTwoTotal = new double[totalGuest];
discountThreeTotal = new double[totalGuest];
discountFourTotal = new double[totalGuest];
```

Now each of the guests will have their own total variables in the array. In your loop, you could use them something like this:

```
discountThreeTotal[i] = optionTotalOne + optionTotalTwo + optionTotalThree;
```

**Note:** Instead of an array, you could also use a List, but that I might go beyond what you've learned so far.

Comment: Will I be able to add the numbers in the array and add them? like this:     System.out.println(discountOneTotal[j] + "  " + discountTwoTotal[k] + "  " + discountFourTotal[l] + "  " + discountThreeTotal[l]);

Comment: Absolutely you can do that!